# Blog design is off for monthly view

Tags: bug, design, blog

http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/

Something is wrong with your layout there:

[image]

Comment: +1 You are right: Firefox (mis-)renders the page in the same way.  Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: The appearance appears to be because of Kastellec & Leoni image in the latter half of the article. In the normal view it is shrunk, but in the monthly view for some reason it is larger than the allotted width so it brings everything with it. I wonder why that is.

Comment: Good news is we've found an explanation for it. I don't know how much the holidays are going to interfere with getting it fixed but I'll keep you guys posted for when it's ready to fix.

Comment: @GraceNote Cool! No rush, I think this is one of the *really* minor issues.